# How to connecth VM with Host while using VPN on host machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, vmware-workstation, cisco-vpn-client

I'm trying to connect Virtual Machine with Host (I use VMWARE) while using VPN in host machine.
When the VPN is off, I can ping my network adapters, it works fine. As soon as I turn VPN ON  I can't ping adapters and other devices from one system to another. I use cisco VPN which gives me access to my company network which I need on VM, but I can't have the VPN on VM(company is blocking :<).
I use NAT type of network.
Is it even possible to run VPN on host, have the VPN network on VM, and still have a connection HOST - VM so I can share data between network devices?

Comment: Which VM are you using? VMware is a firm, making vmware player, wmware workstation, eSXi ... etc)

Comment: vmware workstation pro 15

Comment: Is your VPN Split Tunnel?  If not, that may be the issue.

Comment: It probably is not I will look at it. Whats weird is that I can ping devices between two VMs while having VPN on.

Comment: Split tunnel is no go for me.

Comment: It's likely a restriction put in place by whomever your VPN provider is to prevent data loss.